# Apache .htaccess mapping non-existent file to a script

Tags: apache, .htaccess

This is .htaccess file I currently have:

```
Options -Indexes
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
ErrorDocument 403 /error.html
ErrorDocument 404 /error.html
<Files ".ht*">
    Require all granted
</Files>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^error\.html$ / [R=301]
RewriteRule ^\.ht / [L,R=301,NC]
```

I need to add a specific rule to map a non-existent file to a script, like so:

```
RewriteRule /folder/file.txt /folder/file.php [L]
```

How do I add this rule to the .htaccess?

I tried:

```
Options -Indexes
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
ErrorDocument 403 /error.html
ErrorDocument 404 /error.html
<Files ".ht*">
    Require all granted
</Files>
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond "%{REDIRECT_URL}" "/folder/file.txt"
RewriteRule ^error\.html$ /folder/file.php [L]

RewriteRule ^error\.html$ / [R=301]
RewriteRule ^\.ht / [L,R=301,NC]
```

but it doesn't work.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples, please try following htaccess Rules file. Make sure to keep your htaccess file in root directory.

Also make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/folder/file\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^folder/file\.txt$ /folder/file.php [NC,L]
```

---

---

***OR*** in case you want to match any .txt in uri not only file.txt then try following Rules, make sure to try either above rules set OR following one at a time only.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/folder/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^folder/([^.]*)\.txt$ /folder/$1.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

To map a non-existent file  `/folder/file.txt` to `/folder/file.php` you can use the following :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^folder/file\.txt$ /folder/file.php [L]
```

Here is a generic rule that rewrites all `.txt` files to `.php`

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)\.tx$ /$1.php [L]
```

Comment: @user1481126 aha . Then check the first rule in my answer.